# Returning row array

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database which I'm querying: `"select email from users where access=1"`. The error I'm receiving is

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object on line: `$result = $mysqli->query($query);`

I'm using https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php as a reference and I can't see where I'm querying a mixture of Procedural and Object oriented PHP.

```
<?php

$db_host = "";
$db_user = "";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "";

/* OOP MYSQLI DATABASE CONNECTION */
$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

/*LOGIN QUERY */
$query = "select email from users where access=1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$email= $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);    
if(isset($email[0])){    
    $query1="select id from user where email='".$email[0]."' and facebook=1";
    $result1 = $mysqli->query($query1);
    $email1= $result1->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);  
    $userId=$admin[0];
}
?>
```

Would someone mind explaining please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your MySQLi object is not named `$mysqli`, its named `$db`

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Should be

```
$result = $db->query($query);
```

Same goes for

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
```

Should be

```
if ($db->connect_error) {
```

**Edit**

Just a side note, your second query makes no sense at all :) You just fetched an email from that table and then you are querying the same table again for that email?

```
$email= $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);    
if(isset($email[0])){    
$query1="select id from user where email='".$email[0]."' and facebook=1";
```

All that setup is equivalent to your first query being

```
select id,email from users where access=1 and facebook=1
```

And you don't need that second query then